# How can i pass data from parent component to a child component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new in Vue.js i don't know how can i pass data from parent component to child component on click. I tried with props but it did not worked. So i have a modal and i wanna pass data to it when i open it on click.

Button

```
<div class="m-widget14__header_menu">
   <button v-on:click="doSomethingWith" type="button" class="btn btn-accent btn-md m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createContactModal"><i class="la la-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

Parent script

```
<script>
import ContactModalCreate from './ContactModalCreate.vue'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      footer: [], 
      user: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doSomethingWith(user) {
        this.user = {name: 'Mario'}
        console.log('user', this.user)
    }
  },
  components: {
    'contact-modal-create': ContactModalCreate
  }
}
</script>
```

Child component, for now i just wanna set the name in header for example.

```
<h5 class="modal-title" id="createContactModalLabel">{{ user.name }}</h5>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['user'],
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

So i imported the child component in the parent component, and the child component is called then right? So can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Try {{ $parent.user.name }} in the child. Vue discourages this practice but going the convention way you’d have to declare and pass a prop. This is slightly less code to write and it works.

Comment: I need to pass it like this this.$parent._data.user.name, but can i do that with props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `prop` in your modal declaration.

Somewhere in parent template:

```
<div class="m-widget14__header_menu">
   <button v-on:click="doSomethingWith" type="button" class="btn btn-accent btn-md m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createContactModal"><i class="la la-plus"></i></button>
</div>

<contact-modal-create :user="user"></contact-modal-create>
```

Notice the addition of `:user="user"`  above.

And in your **Child component**, add a `v-if`, because `user` doesn't always have a `name` (it can be `null`, as it is when the parent initializes - see parent's `data() { ..., user: null }`):

```
<h5 class="modal-title" id="createContactModalLabel">
    <span v-if="user">{{ user.name }}</span>
</h5>
```

If you don't add this `v-if`, you'll get an exception when the page loads (again, because `user` is initialized as `null` and `null` has no `name` property).

Answer (score 0):

You should simply try this :

```
data () {
    return {
        footer: [], 
        user: { name: '' }
    }
},
```

Read more about [Reactivity and How Changes Are Tracked](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).